# To Participate in non-Muslims religious activities like halloween, Christmas

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim

All Praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

**What should parents do when their kids go to Public Schools in those countries  where schools are eager to celebrate Halloween, Christmas or their other religious celebrations**

1. Should their kids not participate in those activities and tell the teachers that they are not interested or can they do some activities like wearing costumes for Halloween ,trick or treat, decorating Christmas tree?
2. Some Masajid arrange special events in same day for Muslim kids like magic shows and others where they distribute candies so kids dont feel to go for trick or treat activities so is it allowed to do such in premises?

3  .  What Islam says about those Muslims who participate in  nonmuslims religious activities?

Comment: Oops, the above-mentioned issue is indeed so significant specially in nowadays family. And unfortunetely the parents don't pay so heed to these matters. Actually paying attention to these items as you named them nicely, would make a better and stronger Islamic future for their children. God Bless You for inquiring such important matter.

Comment: I like to mention that halloween is not a religious event. In fact it was invented to replace the religious Reformation Day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
               In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

First of all, as @American Muslim mentioned, you have asked so many questions. In the meantime I suggest you to ask them in at least two separated questions in order to obtain better answers.

> As you inquired:
>
> Should their kids not participate in those activities and tell the
>   teahers that they are not interested or can they do some activities
>   like wearing costumes for Halloween ,trick or treat, decorating
>   Christmas tree?
>
> Some Masajid arrange special events in same day for Muslim kids like
>   magic shows and others where they distribute candies so kids dont feel
>   to go for trick or treat activities so is it allowed to do such in
>   premises?
>
> 3 . What Islam says about those Muslims who participate in nonmuslims
>   religious activities?

**Concise answer:**

1: Yeah, it is the duty of their parents to avoid letting them participating in such activities which are related to non-Muslim religions. Otherwise they would be partner in the sin. And actually it can be considered as a wajib act for them to avoid …

2: This kind of magic would be permissible if it is just a simple jugglery, but it could be a problem if it teach them deceit …

3: to the best of my knowledge, regarding your last question “What Islam says about those Muslims who participate in non-Muslims religious activities?”, on the whole, Islam doesn’t allow participating in such religious activities of non-Muslims due to some reasons such as:

- Your attendance will be considered as propagandizing for their
  beliefs …
- Your attendance will confirm their act (unwanted) …
- Your attendance perhaps effect on you unwanted …

  ---

Reference:

[www.parsine.com](http://www.parsine.com/fa/news/215397/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D8%AC%D8%B4%D9%86-%DA%A9%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA)

Answer (score 2):

You asked so many questions, I'll try to get them all:

> 3 . What Islam says about those Muslims who participate in non-Muslims religious activities?

The Prophet (PBUH) [said](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/745):

> حَدَّثَنَا مُوسَى بْنُ إِسْمَاعِيلَ، حَدَّثَنَا حَمَّادٌ، عَنْ حُمَيْدٍ، عَنْ أَنَسٍ، قَالَ قَدِمَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم الْمَدِينَةَ وَلَهُمْ يَوْمَانِ يَلْعَبُونَ فِيهِمَا فَقَالَ ‏"‏ مَا هَذَانِ الْيَوْمَانِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالُوا كُنَّا نَلْعَبُ فِيهِمَا فِي الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ ‏.‏ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ أَبْدَلَكُمْ بِهِمَا خَيْرًا مِنْهُمَا يَوْمَ الأَضْحَى وَيَوْمَ الْفِطْرِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) came to Medina, the people had two days on which they engaged in games. He asked: What are these two days (what is the significance)? They said: We used to engage ourselves on them in the pre-Islamic period. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: Allah has substituted for them something better than them, the day of sacrifice and the day of the breaking of the fast.

Many scholars took this hadith as a forbiddance to celebrate non Muslim holidays. However, note that the Prophet did not forbid but simply said they were replaced.

Celebrating Christmas (Mowalid Alnabi Issa) is on the same level of Celebrating the Mowalid Alnabi Mohamed, many classify it as Bida that is forbidden as it was never done by the prophet, companions or their followers.

Celebrating atheist holidays, are our of the question, this includes any Muslim/Jewish/Christian holidays that have shirk in them.

Since you didn't ask about non-religious holidays, I won't mention it but that question itself has been answered (disputed).

> 1.Should their kids not participate in those activities and tell the teachers that they are not interested or can they do some activities like wearing costumes for Halloween ,trick or treat, decorating Christmas tree?

I wouldn't recommend they do, imo, since they are small and easily impressionable. You can spurge on them once Islamic holidays come and explain to them why they shouldn't be celebrating holidays they don't believe in.

> 2.Some Masajid arrange special events in same day for Muslim kids like magic shows and others where they distribute candies so kids don't feel to go for trick or treat activities so is it allowed to do such in premises?

I am guessing that the Imam or leader of such Masjid made such decision, it is not for us to judge him until you speak to him and explain your point of view and his and why they are doing so. Personally, Magic shows I wouldn't do in the Masjid as some scholars say that trickery is part of Shirk.

However, if you are in America most of the times that you can see your family is during such holidays, specially if your family is not Muslim, in such cases it doesn't hurt to join them in such celebration in the basis of `Silat Alrhim`.

Here are some Fatwa in regards to the forbiddance of celebration and their reasons, most of them are extreme in such that even holiday greetings are forbidden:

- [islamqa.info](http://islamqa.info/en/947)
- [www.islamweb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/en/article/156439/)
- [http://islam1.org](http://islam1.org/khutub/Non-Muslim_Holidays_Prohibited.htm)

You have both sides, it is up to you to choose.

Comment: JazakAllah for your answer ,well some Muslim parents I know they have started to celebrate so their kids dont feel apart from their teachers and friends and they  consider their intention to be pure as not part of the festival but just for their kids.