# Can I celebrate Halloween by dressing up at school the theme is harry potter?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, celebration

I would like to know, because I've done it in the past.

Comment: In addition to my answer, you ought to repent for what you have done as a related items of non-Muslims, and endeavor and do your best not to repeat ... (if you are interested in doing what is permissible or not based on Islam ...) / Good luck dear smart curious mate.

Comment: check this http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28065/to-participate-in-non-muslims-religious-activities-like-halloween-christmas

Answer (score 1):

Islam concern about being on track on your life. What is your purpose being there? If this events means worshiping to an other God then Allah, or practicing some pray for an other religion, yes, Islam forbids. 
But people in there just having fun and not doing stuff which Islam forbids(i.e. sins) it's not forbidden to attend.
Islam suggests not to go to near haram. So be careful about what you are doing. Islam also suggest not waste time. However this doesn't mean Islam forbids having fun.
It's all about your intentions.
I suggest you to read [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/28067/3466) also.

Answer (score 0):

### In the name of Allah

---

There could be some points concerning what you have asked as:

> Can I celebrate Halloween by dressing up at school the theme is harry
>   potter?

It can be remarked that by your attendance (and doing like what you have done) would be deemed as being a partner in that negative act. And actually it can be counted among the wajib (obligatory) acts for you to avoid …

Regarding a similar related question “What Islam says about those Muslims who participate in non-Muslims religious activities?”, on the whole, Islam doesn’t allow participating in such religious activities of non-Muslims due to some reasons such as:

- Your attendance (celebrating, dressing up and so on) will be
  considered as propagandizing for their beliefs …
- Your attendance (and …) as a Muslim will confirm their act (unwanted)
  …
- Your attendance (and…) perhaps effects on you unwanted …

---

**Reference and more info. :**

- [www.parsine.com](http://www.parsine.com/fa/news/215397/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D8%AC%D8%B4%D9%86-%DA%A9%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA)

Comment: Does celebrating a non Muslim holiday one must have clear intention to why he is celebrating? Like if he celebrates it such as Halloween just for socializing and for having fun with others and be friendly with others, does this will make it is be permissible with condition for the person not to believe in their believes?

Answer (score 0):

It's not appropriate, if you look from Sunnah aspect. Because our Prophet (PBUH) warned us to not wear like non-Muslims or attend their special activities even cut nails. There are so many reasons we might not understand, but in my opinion it can affect negatively to our faith and besides, other behaviors of us. Furthermore, it's really great to ask for it and it shows you're trying to be a good Muslim. It's very very nice when you have doubt about something.

Essalumualaykum.

Comment: Asak ... plz eloborate on the 'cut nails' part. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Are you going to involve in haram such as using drugs, consuming alcohol, having sex, etc.? Or you are just hanging out with your friends? As long as its in a safe environment and nothing contrary to sharia is being done, there is no problem for you to go!

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to leran more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour](http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help) and [write a good answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).