# Can I walk people while they are trick or treating?

Tags: halal-haram

I know its haram to celebrate Halloween, but my little brother and sister still do it. Since they are young, my dad wants me to watch them and I might have to walk with them as they are trick or treating. Is this haram? Is it also haram to pass out candy to the kids?

Comment: If you believe that celebrating Halloween is Haram (I personally don't think its Haram as its more of a social day than a religious one), then it is indeed Haram to help others perform it.

Comment: you can check this http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28065/to-participate-in-non-muslims-religious-activities-like-halloween-christmas

Comment: somewhat related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/can-i-celebrate-halloween-by-dressing-up-at-school-the-theme-is-harry-potter/28347#28347

Comment: You shouldn't celebrate Halloween as it is imitating the kufaar.

Comment: @Armaan one cannot celebrate Halloween because, it might be there something haram(e.g. smocking, doing devil things, scaring people etc...)? I thought that a Muslim can have fun, and why he couldn’t have fun by celebrating? He is only associating with others not imitating, right? And a Muslim can think and disagree about the belief of Halloween, because it is not true belief and not even chosen for us by God in order to celebrate it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Salaam, the celebration itself is not haram singly. But if any haram work(like wine cellar) was done in it, the celebration will be haram too, And helping in or joining some haram work is not correct(is haram) and you should persuade your parents and brothers and sisters not to do haram. if they not believe in it, no one blames you!

Comment: as a related issue: [This site](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/can-i-celebrate-halloween-by-dressing-up-at-school-the-theme-is-harry-potter/28347#28347)  / God Bless You.